# Unable to access github API getting bad credentials error

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I am trying to add a custom code check for a PR. After doing some research I found out that it can be done using the API mentioned below.

[POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/check-runs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#create-a-check-run)

Initially, it was giving me this error:

```html
{
    "message": "You must authenticate via a GitHub App.",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/checks#create-a-check-run"
}
```

I followed the guideline provided in this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#generating-a-private-key).

1. I created a GitHub app.
2. Gave it required permission.
3. Generated a private key.
4. Generated a JWT token using the private key.
5. Installed the Github app in the repo too

I created a curl request:

```html
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/X/X-app/check-runs' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.X.X-X-SAFvDnSkaJDjMI2T_BAC2iLlRZ7uNyFSe-X-UgFBFjoFrwsbcYFKfDM8f3FNPYpA6afhr18DLZ6rzu35klA' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "loremipsum"
}'
```

But, now I am getting this error

```html
{
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 22):

I figured this out. The GH documentation is a bit unclear/misleading. Here are the steps to make this work:

- with the JWT bearer token, list your installations and note the installation id for your app

```
$ curl -i \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/app/installations
```

- then get an installation access token for the above id

```
$ curl -i -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/app/installations/:installation_id/access_tokens
```

- then with that token create the check run but use "Authorization: token" header
  `curl -i -H "Authorization: token YOUR_INSTALLATION_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

Comment: I believe the `/app/installations` call needs to be a GET, not a POST. I get a 404 on POST but GET works fine.

Comment: you're right, the first one is a GET. Thanks!

Comment: Np! Great answer btw; just upvoted

Comment: Worked for me. Been struggling for a while to get an access token for testing behavior of a GitHub App. GitHub's documentation is indeed missing this crucial part.

Comment: omg thank you for this! Github's documentation seems great at first but clearly doesn't outline everything you need to do to auth properly. This post was VERY helpful. Thank you!